# Changing language of QGIS Interface

Tags: qgis, internationalization, windows-xp

I want the QGIS interface in English, in order to share information with the GIS community. Using another language, when chatting with the GIS community, makes things more difficult. When I installed QGIS, it automatically set the language to French.

I am using Windows XP in French, but I want QGIS in English.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Sure, just go to the options dialog:

`Préférences->Options->Langue` (`Settings->Options->Locale`)

Check `Forcer la nationalité du système` (`Override system locale`) and set you language in there.

Answer (score 11):

No need to uninstall QGIS.

All QGIS settings are stored in the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS\QGIS\`

If you look for the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS\QGIS\locale` you will see it has a `overrideFlag` and `userLocale` setting.  Make sure that `overrideFlag` is set to false.

You can also start QGIS with a command line arg to tell it which language to use:

```
qgis.bat --lang en_US
```

Once you are in QGIS head to Settings -> Options -> Locale and make sure `override system locale` is unticked and that the additional info section gives you the correct language, mine is en_AU for example.

Answer (score 5):

I found it at Options/Local then Override system local.

Answer (score 5):

Settings (or extra) --> options --> Locale --> (click to override) then chose language --> restart the programme to apply the new settings